# I want to use the same php application simultaneously in two different browsers but with different user input values for the variables?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

The application is a chat application with login verification. It implements Ajax, PHP, MySQL, and HTML. Everything works except that when two users are logged in under different names, after they type the first message and the page refreshes both their browsers synchronize as if they are the same user. They end up having a conversation with themselves. I need both user to be able to update the database with their message separately as individual users and have the application distinguish between the two users.

This is the query that updates the message column of the database of the user sending the message:

```
$query = "UPDATE chatLogs SET msg = '$msg' WHERE userName='$uName'";
```

This is how I am grabbing the user info and the buddy in the database that they wish to speak to:

```
<?php

    $uName = $_POST["userName"];
    $pwd = $_POST["pwd"];
    $buddy = $_POST["chatBuddy"];

    $result = $link->query($query);


   if(!$row=$result->fetch_assoc()){

      header("Location: chat.php");
   }

   else{
      $_SESSION['userName'] = $uName;
      $_SESSION['chatBuddy'] = $buddy;
      header("Location: chatBox.php");
  }
```

?>

Comment: can you describe more clearly ? And why you use `if(!$row=` ! ??

Comment: Also the code allows SQL injections, please use prepared statements!